# Question about splitting the vertices up into pairwise connected trees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-minors

Let $G=(V, E)$ be an undirected simple graph. 
I couldn't find the formal definition, so let's call a subset $V'\subset V$ a chunk , if it's either a singular vertex or if every pair of it's vertices are connected by a path of vertices that all belong to $V'$. Thus a chunk can be represented as a singular vertex or a tree. We say that two disjoint chunks "touch" if there is an edge connecting  a vertex from one chunk  to a vertex from the other chunk. If this edge is also unique, then we say that the chunks touch uniquely.

My understanding is that  $G$ having the complete graph $K_n$ as minor, is equivalent to $G$ having $n$ disjoint chunks that are pairwise touching.

My question is: if $G$ has $n$ disjoint chunks that are pairwise touching, can we then also find $n$ disjoint chunks that are pairwise uniquely touching?

I have mostly looked at planar graphs and well known graphs like the Peterson to look for counterexamples, but could easily find n uniquely touching chunks in most of them. But I can't find a formal argument why this would be the case, nor a way to show it by induction. Do you think this is true, or can provide a counter example, let me know.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is there any difference between a "chunk" and a "vertex set of some connected subgraph"?

Comment: If not then "chunks" correspond one-to-one with "maximal connected subgraphs".

Comment: But they don't have to be maximal. A chunk could be for example (Canada, USA, Mexico). So yeah, a connected subgraph

Comment: I worded that comment badly. But my point is that for each chunk there exists a connected subgraph whose vertex set is that chunk, and among that collection of subgraphs there exists one which is maximal, namely the union of all the edges whose vertex set is that chunk. Borrowing from the language of [flag complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_complex) one might call this subgraph the *flag graph* spanned by that chunk.

Comment: So to correct my earlier comment, "chunks" correspond one-to-one with "connected flag subgraphs".

Comment: The square pyramid graph has a $K_4$ minor, but can't be decomposed with chunks that are pairwise uniquely touching